# Manipulating individual products in MySQL table

Tags: php, html, mysql, cart

I am working on a small orders cart and currently I have implemented MySQL to display products from a database. I want these products to have their own images and to be organised into 3 separate tables for starters, mains and desserts.

Currently I have one table for all items and I am unsure how to add an image next to a selected product.

Shown here:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<?php

session_start();

$page = 'index.php';

mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('cart') or die(mysql_error());

if (isset($_GET['add'])) {
    $quantity = mysql_query('SELECT id, quantity FROM products WHERE id='.mysql_real_escape_string((int)$_GET['add']));
    while ($quantity_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($quantity)) {
        if ($quantity_row['quantity']!=$_SESSION['cart_'.(int)$_GET['add']]) {
            $_SESSION['cart_' . (int)$_GET['add']] +='1';
            header('Location: ' . $page);

    }
}
header('Location: ' . $page);

}

if (isset($_GET['remove'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart_'.(int)$_GET['remove']]--;
    header ('Location: ' . $page);

}

if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart_' . (int)$_GET['delete']]='0';
    header ('Location: ' . $page);
}



function products() {
    $get = mysql_query('SELECT id, name, description, price FROM products WHERE quantity > 0 ORDER BY id ASC');
    if (mysql_num_rows($get) == 0) {
        echo "There are no products to display.";
    }
    else {
    echo "<center>\n";
    echo "  <table border=2 width=40% cellspacing=5 cellpadding=10 bgcolor=cyan cols=2>\n";
    echo "      <tr>\n";
    echo "      <th>View</th>\n";
    echo "      <th>Dish</th>\n";
    echo "      <th>Description</th>\n";
    echo "      <th>Item Price</th>\n";
    echo "      </tr>\n";
    while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {

    ?>
    <tr>
        <td> <a href="ice.png"</a> </td>
        <td> <?echo '<p>'.$get_row['name']?> </td>
        <td> <?echo $get_row['description']?> </td>
        <td> <?echo '&pound'.number_format($get_row['price'],2).'<br><br> <a href="cart.php?add='.$get_row['id'].'">Add</a></p>';?> </td>
    </tr>
    <?
    } 
    echo "</table>\n";
    echo "</center>\n";
}
}
```

Comment: Store the path to the web path or disk path of the image in the database. Then show the image with `<img src="[src]" />`

Comment: @Halcyon thanks for your reply, could you show me a small working example of what you mean? I am new to programming

Comment: @JamesPatterson can you show the code that prints the blue table?

Comment: @Halcyon I think I already have this displayed? It is implemented under the products function line

Comment: Oh right, I didn't see that. Where you have `<a href="ice.png"</a>` should be: `<img src="ice.png" />` and then replace `ice.png` by a value you pull from the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a field to a table with a type of product.
So you will be able to perform 3 separate queries with the condition.
For Example

```sql
SELECT
  id,
  name,
  description,
  price
FROM
  products
WHERE
  quantity > 0 
  AND type LIKE 'desert'
ORDER BY id ASC
```

and so on